# Compare the first item of a list with the last one of another list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, compare, swap

I am trying to compare two different lists, but the comparation must be succesful  when the first and the last items of the lists are equal and vice versa, while the other items of the lists must be equal.

So the thing must be that

```
cmp([a,b,c,d,e],[e,b,c,d,a]).
true.
```

With the following code we succeed but only with the first two items of the lists:

```
swap([X,Y],[Y,X]).
swap([X,Y|T],[Y,X|Z]):- T=Z.
```

Some idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the `append/3` approach that @gusbro presented (+1). Another way to do this is with an auxiliary predicate that carries the elements you want along. This is a minor variation on the problem of [swapping the first and last elements of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071799/prolog-swap-first-and-last-elements-in-list).

```
cmp([A|As], [B|Bs]) :-
    cmp(As, A, B, Bs).

cmp([A], B, A, [B]).
cmp([_, A|As], X, Y, [_, B|Bs]) :-
    cmp([A|As], X, Y, [B|Bs]).

| ?- cmp([a,b,c,d,e],[e,b,c,d,a]).

true ? a

no
| ?- cmp(A, B).

A = [C,D]
B = [D,C] ? ;

A = [C,_,D]
B = [D,_,C] ? ;

A = [C,_,_,D]
B = [D,_,_,C] ? ;

A = [C,_,_,_,D]
B = [D,_,_,_,C] ? ;
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use [append/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append/3) to get the first and last item, and use it again with those items interchanged:

```
cmp(A, B):-
  append([First|Tail], [Last], A),
  append([Last|Tail], [First], B).
```